# Seperate AddHandlers in WPF ListView Column Header Click event

Tags: c#, wpf

How to use the same addhandler for 2 different listview GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent in WPF ?

I have 2 WPF listview in same window and i want to implement Sorting when clicking on Column header of both list view. For getting click event, we need to do the addhandler as shown below.

In the Window_Loaded event

```
this.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnClicked));
```

And the event handler is

```
 private void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {.....}
```

If i click on the both list view's column header, the above event will fire. but how to make it seperate calls ?

Comment: Why not `GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent += OnClicked;`

Comment: But how to associate this event with 2 seperate listview's ?

Comment: You can cast the sender parameter to your concrete control type and then you get the specific clicked ListView.